# Detect points that are very scattered from the rest of the data

Tags: algorithm, statistics, detection

I have a set of results (numbers), and I would like to know if a given result is very good/bad compared to the **previous** results (only previous).

Each result is a number € IR+. For example if you have the sequence `10, 11, 10, 9.5, 16` then 16 is clearly a very good result compared to the previous ones. I would like to find an algorithm to detect this situation (very good/bad result compared to previous results).

[image]

A more general way to state this problem is : how to determine if a point - in a given set of data - is scattered from the rest of the data.

Now, that might look like a peak detection problem, but since the previous values are not constant there are many tiny peaks, and I only want the big ones.

My first idea was to compute the mean and determine the standard deviation but it is quite limited. Indeed, if there is **one** huge/low value in the previous results it will change dramatically the mean/stadard deviation and the next results will have to be even greater/lower to beat the standard deviation (in order to be detected) and therefor many points will not be (properly) detected.

I'm quite sure that must a well known problem.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: clustering probably suits your needs best if you rate the new value as ordinary if a result of similar magnitude occurred _at least once_ in the data history. in this case dismiss all schemes that try to average out previous results, eg. using some sort of [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Comment: In fact, the values in the data set can be increasing/decreasing. Therefore, the idea of looking if a result of similar magnitude occured at least once, probably would unfortunatly not work when there is a "trend" in the data (increasing/decreasing).

Comment: will the trend be linear ?

Comment: It could be anything (not necessarly linear) .. The data has a _little_ randomness in itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem is called [Anomaly Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection).

Comment: You're right, thank you :p Other people having the same problem I did might want to look up `outlier detection`